# Save the first value of field A in field B in sObject

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I have a custom field called Unit Price and First Value.

Unit price is get upating evrytime.

How can i save first time entered **Unit price** value in **First Value** field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Workflow Rule with Field Update.

When `Unit price` is getting updated, check if `First Value` is empty. If so, then simply populate it with `Unit price` value.

You can find more about Workflow Rules [in Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm) and [this article is also a good place to start.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workflow_Rules)

Comment: Thank you, Is there anything that I can do with validation rules?

Comment: I guess there's no need to. Validation rules throw errors on some invalid (defined by you) values.

Answer (score 0):

Also this can be done bt applying **If else condition**.

I resolved it just by adding a condition in controller like

```
IF(First value == NULL){
    First Value = Unit Price;
}
```

In this way I can add only first inserted unit price in First value.
This resolved my problem.